# BK - Tree Search All

Tags: algorithm, search, data-structures, fuzzy-search, bk-tree

A [BK Trees (Burkhard-Keller Trees)](http://blog.notdot.net/2007/4/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Part-1-BK-Trees) is associated with fuzzy string searches (e.g. spell check, word recommendations). And all the BK Trees searching algorithm are the same as [explained here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bk-tree-introduction-implementation/). The aim is to return, for example, ["seek" and "peek" if I search for "aeek"](http://thingswelearned.com/article/show/bk-tree-burkhard-keller-trees).

Now, my question is, I'm trying to use this fuzzy string searches algorithm to search for *all* similar items from the *given dictionary*. For example, given a word "seek", I want to find *all* similar words, like "peek", "geek", "seat", etc within the dictionary. However I found the [BK Trees searching algorithm that everyone uses](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bk-tree-introduction-implementation/) is not designed for that.

Take a look my [sample test result here](https://github.com/go-dedup/simhash/blob/master/sho/bktree_test.go#L96-L163). I found that [the dictionary will be different if the feeding words order is different, thus the search result can be different as well](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/golang-nuts/uE99XUB08hw/).

What I want is, using my above [sample test](https://github.com/go-dedup/simhash/blob/master/sho/bktree_test.go#L96-L163), given any of the four Python books, a `SearchAll` function will always return the four Python books, despite the order the dictionary is built, or the order the search is done.

However, I've tried many ways but all failed (e.g., [this is one of them](https://gist.github.com/suntong/8e13f34d218d42bafda747d260bc270d)). Now I'm throwing up my hands and asking for help. A pseudo code or generic algorithm describing would do. Thx.

Comment: @templatetypedef?

Comment: @Duck, would you be able to help pls?

Answer (score 1):

You have an integer overflow on lines [77](https://github.com/go-dedup/simhash/blob/master/sho/bktree.go#L77) and [106](https://github.com/go-dedup/simhash/blob/master/sho/bktree.go#L106) of bktree.go:

> k := d - r

Since the types of `d` and `r` are `uint8`, the type of `k` is also `uint8`, so when `d < r`, `k` ends up larger than `d + r`, and the following cycle doesn't execute.

You can fix it like this:

```
k := int16(d) - int16(r)
max_k  := int16(d) + int16(r)
if k < 1 {
    k = 1
}
for ; k <= max_k; k++ {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Actually, that won't happen, as in lines https://github.com/go-dedup/simhash/blob/master/sho/bktree.go#L73-L74, I.e., when on lines 77 and 106, `d` would be `>= r`. But thanks for taking time looking into it!

Comment: I went through it with the debugger, and it does happen on the line [106](https://github.com/go-dedup/simhash/blob/master/sho/bktree.go#L106). Moreover, after the fix, `ExampleSearch_filesA`, `ExampleSearch_filesB`, `ExampleSearch_filesS` all output the same result.

Comment: Oh, there! Thanks A LOT! what debugger are you using BTW?

Comment: @xpt I was using JetBrains Gogland.

Comment: thanks @user3290797, sorry that I can only up-vote, because I'm still hoping there is a `SearchAll` function that can always return the four Python books for each of them.